# How to install TWRP or root device

Tags: root-access

I'm trying to install TWRP but it says (**boot image with correct signature or disable verified boot**)

My device is (**Umidigi power**)

Or root my device
I have try with this:

```
UniversalAndroot
Framaroot
Magisk Manager
Magisk v20
KingoRoot
```

Can someone help me with this?

**Note 24/1-2020 17:31**

```
step 1: adb reboot bootloader
step 2: fastboot flashing unlock
step 3: Volume Up
```

Follow the guide here: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=79819558&postcount=8

**SP_Flash_Tool** for **magisk_patched_boot.img** in boot sector in **SP_FLash_Tool**

Install **Magisk Manager** V20.3 new version. and here we go. thanks for all imput :)

Comment: enable oem unlocking in developer options and start with unlocking bootloader from fastboot

Comment: Thanks i use (fastboot flashing unlock) works for me

Answer (score 1):

**Follow these steps carefully (*It's almost same for every android devices*):**

> 1. Install ADB in your PC. Update the drivers of your device.
> 2. Boot your phone into recovery mode. (Make sure you turned on USB Debugging and OEM from developer options).
> 3. Open the ADB in your PC and check your phone is connected by USB or
>      not. If it shows your phone in terminal then proceed further.
> 4. Reboot into fastboot.
> 5. Then unlock the bootloader (*fastboot oem unlock*).
> 6. After unlocking the bootloader flash the TWRP recovery's img file (*Be careful becuase TWRP recovery isn't same for every phone. You've
>      to go tho their website and find your phone's. If it's not available
>      in their website then don't worry you'll find it in unofficial
>      websites*).
> 7. Now boot your phone into recovery mode. This will open TWRP recovery now.
> 8. Now you should use ADB sideload method or use your phones internal or external memory to store magisk zip and flash it using TWRP.

*You don't need to use KingoRoot to root. Magisk is an amazing tool to root any device.*

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about this device myself but, I have managed to find a thread over on XDA that contains a very beginner oriented guide on how to root the Umidigi power.

https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=79819558&postcount=8

This post is actually part of a thread on installing TWRP on the phone, however, after a quick read I couldn't easily see instructions for installing TWRP itself.

Comment: I know that it is convention to post a detailed guide here, or at least an outline of the guide I have linked to but, this is an extensive walk through of the steps involved and I didn't want to take any credit away from the OP on XDA by passing it off as my own.

Comment: Giving a brief description of required steps is recommended. If the target post gets deleted or modified, your answer would become useless.